# Using Activity class static members in a background service

Tags: android, service, android-context

My app has an Activity class called MainActivity and one of its members is

```
public static SharedPreferences prefsdefault;
```

My app has also a service (in another process) which runs in background. Inside the service I wrote

```
MainActivity.prefsdefault.getString(Key,"Hello");
```

The app sometimes throws null pointer exception at this line. Why? Does it mean that this member is cleaned up by the garbage collector when I close the activity and I cannot access it at anytime (when my service runs)? So what is the perfect solution for this?

Should I pass the MainActiviy.class to the service? It also happens when I implement a thread that requires a context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because, even if your prefsdefault may have been initialized once, your whole app can be garbage collected and restarted again.

In that case your service will find that field as null. Using static fields inside activities is wrong for a bunch of reasons, the most important is that your app may be killed and restarted by the operating system and after that all the static fields are wiped out again.

The correct way to use shared preferences is to access them using getSharedPreferences whenever you need to access / write.

The other weird thing is that you say that the service runs in another process. In that case it should not be able to access to data from another process.

Comment: I did not understand the word "wiped out", If I have in my activity static boolean x = true and it is set to false in the app. Now if the OS restarted my app, would x be True or False?

Comment: It would be true. For the same reason if you have an object initialized somewhere, if the os needs your app's resources, the pointer to that object becomes null.

Comment: Is that the reason I should avoid using static fields in Activity? Now if I want to call (from my activity) a thread  which requires information from objects declared in the Activity? What is then the solution? Pass the MainActivity.class to the Thread constructor? Maybe?

Comment: Use async tasks if you need one shot threads (ie - perform a job and return), or loopers if you need to have a long time running thread. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html You can use handlers to pass messages between different threads.

Answer (score 0):

Because `prefsdefault` is `NULL`. I don't see that it is initialized. 
You can do that by

```
prefsdefault = getSharedPreferences("my_preferences", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

**Hot tip: Never make your `SharedPreference` instance *static*.**

Comment: What about other objects like context required for a thread want to play sounds? Pass the MainActivity to the constructor? Is it the perfect idea?

Comment: @yasserbn Hard to say without seeing more code, it really depends; But don't make SharedPreference static.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is `SharedPreferences` is not initialised u dont need to do like this as `SharedPreferences` are global available with in app if MODE is Private just create new instance in service as well it will work