# Android Service access to static member of another class

Tags: android, service, static, locationlistener

I have a problem with my android service. In the "onLocationChanged", i want to access a static member of my class "Device".

I start my service with :

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, LocationService.class);
   startService(i);
```

This is my class LocationListener with the service:

```
private class LocationListener implements android.location.LocationListener{
    Location mLastLocation;
    LocationListener(String provider)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "LocationListener " + provider);
        mLastLocation = new Location(provider);
    }
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
    {
         Device.getLocationType().setLocationData(location);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
    {
      //...
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
    {
       //...
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
    {
        //...
    }
}


LocationListener[] mLocationListeners = new LocationListener[] {
        new LocationListener(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER),
        new LocationListener(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)
};


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0)
{
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    Toast.makeText(this, "service starting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "onStartCommand");
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onCreate()
{
    super.onCreate();
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
    initializeLocationManager();
    try {
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME, MIN_DISTANCE,
                mLocationListeners[1]);
        Log.d(TAG, "try");
    } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
        Log.d(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        Log.d(TAG, "network provider does not exist, " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    try {
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME, MIN_DISTANCE,
                mLocationListeners[0]);
        Log.d(TAG, "try2");
    } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
        Log.d(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        Log.d(TAG, "gps provider does not exist " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    Log.e(TAG, "onDestroy");
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mLocationManager != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < mLocationListeners.length; i++) {
            try {
                mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListeners[i]);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.i(TAG, "fail to remove location listners, ignore", ex);
            }
        }
    }
}


private void initializeLocationManager() {
    Log.e(TAG, "initializeLocationManager");
    if (mLocationManager == null) {
        mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    }
}
```

My class Device

```
public class Device {
private static LocationType locationType;

//...
}
```

And the class LocationType

```
public class LocationType {
private Location location;

public LocationType(){

    //...
}

Location getLocationData() {
    return location;
}

void setLocationData(Location location) {
    this.location = location;
}
}
```

My application failed because, i don't have the right to access static member from service? How can i access this static member?

Thanks a lot for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `Device.getLocationType()` are you sure this method is also static ? So either make it static or make `locationType` public and access it directly.

Whether you'd want to is another thing entirely.

Also, try to replace :

```
private static LocationType locationType;
```

with :

```
private static LocationType locationType = new LocationType();
```

Comment: Yes, the method getLocationType() in Device is static. And it return an object of LocationType. And i want call the method "setLocationData" of this object. ("setLocationdData" is "protected" so acceccible in the same package.)

Comment: This is very strange but, in the console log, nothing is displayed. Only the app display the message "app has stopped". I click "ok" and the app still running. This message is display each time the programme enter in the "onLocationChanged".

Comment: The service is stopped when I call the method of the object "LocationType".

Comment: I have tried to only retrieve the object and it work :LocationType type = Device.getLocationType(); The service is stopped when i access a non static method or member of this object. How can i access the members and method of this object from the "onLocationChanged"?

Comment: Hard to say without the stack trace. Are you sure that your `LocationType type` is not `null` ? Or maybe setting the setter public ?

Comment: And, important. Are you sure that your `LocationType` has been instanciated somewhere ? Because if you never instanciated it you won't be able to access its methods.

Comment: Yep, thanks for you remarks. My object LocationType is null.... Now, i will see why it is null.. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try to replace `private static LocationType locationType;` with `private static LocationType locationType = new LocationType();`

Answer (score 0):

You field is private

```
private static LocationType locationType;
```

Make it public and it should be accessible

```
public static LocationType locationType;
```

If that isn't desired you should at least make a static getter which is either public or package private. If it's package private, make sure both classes are within the same package.

Comment: I have a getter for this private static member : public static LocationType getLocationType() { return Device.locationType; } And i use the getter to get the object LocationType in the method OnLocationChanged LocationType type =Device.getLocationType();

Comment: Try not referring to it like `Device.locationType` buy just as `locationType`. Since the method is already static you should be able to access it like that.

Comment: Already tried.
I read this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15325882/using-activity-class-static-members-in-a-background-service
I think it's what happens in my case too. 
But i don't understand how i can correct it....

Answer (score 0):

My object "locationType" is always defined to null... In my MainActivity, i call the method Device.init(...). This method create the object LocationType in the static member.

```
public class Device {
private static LocationType locationType;

 public static void init(...){
    Device.locationType = new LocationType(...);

    if(Device.locationType != null){
        Intent i = new Intent(activity, LocationService.class);
        activity.startService(i);
    }
}
```

My service is launched, but in the service method "onLocationChanged", the Device.locationType is null.